# How to animate text weight using Leon Sans with HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fonts

Using the typeface [Leon Sans](https://github.com/cmiscm/leonsans) which allows for dynamic animations via canvas, how can I animate the weight of a given string of text, slightly staggering when each letter gets thicker, like this:

[image: letters getting thicker, one-by-one]

(An animated gif of the desired effect is viewable in the [README](https://github.com/cmiscm/leonsans/blob/master/README.md), in the "What is special" section above the "weight change" list item.)

---

### Working Starter Code

I have a string properly drawing with this suggested starter code:

```
let leon, canvas, ctx;

const sw = 800;
const sh = 600;
const pixelRatio = 2;

function init() {
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = sw * pixelRatio;
    canvas.height = sh * pixelRatio;
    canvas.style.width = sw + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = sh + 'px';
    ctx.scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio);

    leon = new LeonSans({
        text: 'animate this text',
        color: ['#000000'],
        size: 80,
        weight: 200
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function animate(t) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, sw, sh);

    const x = (sw - leon.rect.w) / 2;
    const y = (sh - leon.rect.h) / 2;
    leon.position(x, y);

    leon.draw(ctx);
}

window.onload = () => {
    init();
};
```

([Customized example of working code on Glitch](https://leon-sans-1.glitch.me))

---

### Failed Attempt

And I've been given [this suggestion](https://github.com/cmiscm/leonsans/issues/24) by the creator of the font to use the following code snippet:

```
this.leons_ = [];
this.text_ = String('animate this text').split('');
this.leonTotal_ = this.text_.length;
for (let i = 0; i < this.leonTotal_; i++) {
  const ls = new LeonSans({
    text: this.text_[i],
    color: ['blue'],
    size: 100,
    weight: 200
  });
  this.leons_.push(ls);
}
```

But I still can't make it work. When I try incorporating it this way, I don't get any text on the screen at all:

```
let leon, canvas, ctx;
let leons_, text_, leonTotal_;

const sw = 800;
const sh = 600;
const pixelRatio = 2;

function init() {
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = sw * pixelRatio;
    canvas.height = sh * pixelRatio;
    canvas.style.width = sw + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = sh + 'px';
    ctx.scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio);

    leons_ = [];
    text_ = String('animate this text').split('');
    leonTotal_ = text_.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < leonTotal_; i++) {
      const ls = new LeonSans({
        text: text_[i],
        color: ['blue'],
        size: 100,
        weight: 200
      });
      leons_.push(ls);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function animate(t) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, sw, sh);

    const x = (sw - leon.rect.w) / 2;
    const y = (sh - leon.rect.h) / 2;
    leon.position(x, y);

    leon.draw(ctx);
}

window.onload = () => {
    init();
};
```

And I get the console error:

`leon.js:5316 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rect' of undefined`

referring to this line:

`const x = (sw - leon.rect.w) / 2;`

but I suspect I need to fix my approach before debugging that error specifically.

Any ideas? (Feel free to remix the Glitch project linked to above.)

Thanks.

Comment: In your failed attempt, you are creating and populating a `leons_` Array in the `init` function, but you are trying to call `draw()` of an undefined `leon` variable. You should pick one of `leons_`  ( `leons_[ current ].draw( ctx )` ). However the error message suggests that you are facing yet an other problem, and given it's complaining about accessing a `.rect` property on an `undefined` variable, I'd guess that what should have been a CanvasRenderingContext2D instance in one of the methods was actually undefined.

Comment: Wouldn't the `current` in `leons_[ current ].draw( ctx )` be undefined? Can anyone provide a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I figured it out.

Starting from my failed attempt above, I was able to use the array I created, `leons_`, with `TweenMax.staggerFromTo` to cycle through each letter in the array:

```
TweenMax.staggerFromTo(
  leons_,
  1,
  {
    weight: minWeight,
    size: sw * leonHeightRatio
  },                    
  {
    weight: maxWeight,
    size: sw * leonHeightRatioLarge,
    repeat: -1,
    yoyo: true,
    ease: Power2.easeInOut
  },
0.1);
```

View working code example here: https://leon-sans-staggered-weight-size-animations.glitch.me/